# 464 error with new relic data export from the Java 8 application running with open telemetry agent

Tags: spring-boot, docker, newrelic, open-telemetry

It works fine when I run Java 11:

```
java -javaagent:./otel/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar \
-DOTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_COMPRESSION=gzip \
-DOTEL_SPAN_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_LENGTH_LIMIT=4095 \
-DOTEL_JAVA_DISABLED_RESOURCE_PROVIDERS=io.opentelemetry.sdk.extension.resources.ProcessResourceProvider \
-DOTEL_EXPERIMENTAL_EXPORTER_OTLP_RETRY_ENABLED=true \
-DOTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_TEMPORALITY_PREFERENCE=DELTA \
-Dotel.traces.exporter=otlp \
-Dotel.metrics.exporter=otlp \
-Dotel.logs.exporter=otlp \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317 \
-Dotel.resource.attributes=service.name=app-service \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.headers=api-key=<api-key> \
-Dotel.javaagent.debug=false -jar ./target/app-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But when I run in Java 8, it fails:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", \
  "-Dotel.traces.exporter=otlp", \
  "-Dotel.metrics.exporter=otlp", \
  "-Dotel.logs.exporter=otlp", \
  "-Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317", \
  "-DOTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_COMPRESSION=gzip", \
  "-DOTEL_SPAN_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_LENGTH_LIMIT=4095", \
  "-DOTEL_JAVA_DISABLED_RESOURCE_PROVIDERS=io.opentelemetry.sdk.extension.resources.ProcessResourceProvider", \
  "-DOTEL_EXPERIMENTAL_EXPORTER_OTLP_RETRY_ENABLED=true", \
  "-DOTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_TEMPORALITY_PREFERENCE=DELTA", \
  "-Dotel.exporter.otlp.headers=api-key=<api-key>", \
  "-Dotel.resource.attributes=service.name=app-service", \
  "-Dotel.javaagent.debug=false", \
  "-javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent.jar", "-jar", "app-service.jar"]
```

Getting the following error:

```
[otel.javaagent] [OkHttp https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317/...] WARN io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter - Failed to export logs. Server responded with HTTP status code 464.
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-jdk-8-slim AS build
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY src src
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean install

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY --from=build /opt/app/target/app-service-*.jar app-service.jar
COPY ./otel/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent.jar", "-jar", "app-service.jar"]
```

I am using opentelemetry-javaagent - version: 1.12.0.

Any idea which version of new relic open telemetry agent works for Java 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the issue reported:
https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/java-464-error-with-new-relic-data-export-from-the-java-8-application-running-with-opentelemetry-agent/187361/3?u=valsaraj

Answer (score 0):

464 indicates a problem with protocol mixing - HTTP vs GRPC. Use HTTP explicitly, because grpc exporter has this problem:

```
otel.exporter.otlp.protocol=http/protobuf
```

Maybe you have something (proxy, firewal, WAF, ...) what is causing a problem with GRPC connection from the container.

See doc: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md